# How can I differentate sum of a count for different merchant

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is query which I tried:

```
select distinct 
    MerchantOfferMerchantID, c.PsmHaendlerName as Merchant_name,  
    MerchantOfferUpdateDateUTC, 
    t.MerchantOfferPropertyColumnName, 
    s.MerchantPdlMappingColumnMerchant as column_mapped,
    sum(count(t.MerchantOfferPropertyValueBigint)) over() as SUM_GENDER  
from 
    OFFERPART2.TBLMERCHANTOFFER k 
join 
    OfferPart2.TBLMERCHANTOFFERPROPERTY t on k.MerchantOfferIdentHash = t.MerchantOfferPropertyMerchantOfferIdentHash  
join 
    copy.tblPsmHaendler as c on k.MerchantOfferMerchantID = c.PsmHaendlerID 
join 
    copy.tblMerchantPdlSpecification q on k.MerchantOfferMerchantID = q.MerchantPdlSpecificationMerchantID 
join 
    copy.tblMerchantPdlMapping s on q.MerchantPdlSpecificationID = s.MerchantPdlMappingMerchantPdlSpecificationID    
where 
    MerchantOfferPropertyColumnName like '%gender%' 
    and MerchantPdlMappingColumn like'%Gender%' 
    and MerchantOfferUpdateDateUTC > getdate()-0.5 
group by 
    k.MerchantOfferUpdateDateUTC, t.MerchantOfferPropertyColumnName,
    MerchantOfferMerchantID, c.PsmHaendlerName, 
    s.MerchantPdlMappingColumnMerchant    
order by 
    MerchantOfferUpdateDateUTC desc
```

Result:

[image]

But I want sum_gender of different merchant_id

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT k.MerchantOfferMerchantID,sum(count(t.MerchantOfferPropertyValueBigint)) over() AS SUM_GENDER
FROM OFFERPART2.TBLMERCHANTOFFER k
JOIN OfferPart2.TBLMERCHANTOFFERPROPERTY t ON k.MerchantOfferIdentHash = t.MerchantOfferPropertyMerchantOfferIdentHash
JOIN copy.tblPsmHaendler AS c ON k. MerchantOfferMerchantID = c.PsmHaendlerID
JOIN copy.tblMerchantPdlSpecification q ON k.MerchantOfferMerchantID = q.MerchantPdlSpecificationMerchantID
JOIN copy.tblMerchantPdlMapping s ON q.MerchantPdlSpecificationID = s.MerchantPdlMappingMerchantPdlSpecificationID
WHERE MerchantOfferPropertyColumnName LIKE '%gender%'
  AND MerchantPdlMappingColumn LIKE'%Gender%'
  AND MerchantOfferUpdateDateUTC > getdate()-0.5
GROUP BY 
         k.MerchantOfferMerchantID

ORDER BY k.MerchantOfferMerchantID DESC
```

Comment: it is giving sum_gender of only 1 merchant_id , I want sum_gender of every merchant_id